# How can I make my Android app dependent on a library of custom UI views? Where can I found those after Importing?

Tags: android, view, uiview, android-library

I have some points with me!!

1) Where can I found **custom Android UI View library's** in the web. I have searched a lot and failed obtaining a working one.
2) I **haven't got any *.jar files inside the *zip I've downloaded**.
3) Android studio **can't support zip library's but Eclipse can**.
4) **Where is Graddle file** located in Eclipse.

Now my question is...
*Even I've added one custom UI library and built. The **layout editor palette window's CUSTOM VIEW Tab** in Eclipse will not shows any VIEWS from that added library? Why so? Do I manually write the XML? Please help me..!!! Also where can I find good attractive and colorful UI element library in web?*

Answer (score 0):

1) Where can I found custom Android UI View library's in the web. I have searched a lot and failed obtaining a working one.

ans : It depends on what type of custom ui want. You have got search specific custom ui widgets. Ex : button,TextView etc. You get it library project most of the time so you have advantage customise further as per your need. Jar will be very less.

2) I haven't got any *.jar files inside the *zip I've downloaded.

Ans : As my previous ans zip what you got is library project. Its not jar project. And im sure sure you have got more zip from github repository.

3) Android studio can't support zip library's but Eclipse can.

Ans : You have to unzip and add it as dependency library to project. 
4) Where is Gradle file located in Eclipse

Ans : Gradle file is nothing but build.gradle file or settings.gradle

Comment: Thankyou for your time to help me my friend. I've only a problem that's gone headache. Both in Studio and Eclipse, I can't view the widgets Iam added as dependent to my project

Comment: Help me please. I've downloaded several library's from Android Arsena. All are of Zip type. I can't find any file of jar type while I extracted the content rather than "gradle-wrapper.jar". I've tried FILE/IMPORT/GENERAL/EXISTING PROJECT/<Root directory of downloaded file>. Unfortunately no specific results...!! Also tried PROJECT/PROPERTIES/JAVA BUILD PATH. Where I'm mistaken? Do I have just a class folder that I'm downloaded? Or is it contains a jar?. Please help me...

Comment: Unzip and import as project or module

Comment: I think the Zip need to be opened by Android studio and exported to form a jar. And should be imported to project. Am I correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

1) Good point to start is [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/184)

2) A lot of library can be add to Android Studio Project manually as Module or providing single file with aar extension.
Jar file is not very useful for custom control, because it can`t store android xml resources file, so you can`t declare strings or attributes. Best choice is [aar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) library format.

3) If library contain only class files just rename it from zip to jar and add it to project as usually.

4) Eclipse does`t support graddle build system at all.

In any case, be sure that you add library to Eclipse project and press refresh button on custom view tab.

Comment: I did the step you remarked in the last line. But still the refresh can't detect any views

Comment: I've downloaded https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3201?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C5995302316 from Arsenal. It's a countdown UI element. Now I've the *.zip in my hand. I've added the whole ZIP under dependence in Eclipse and compiled succesfully. But the problem is I can't find that COUNTDOWN view on CUSTOM VIEW tab in Pallets under layout design session. Any suggestions my friend?